# Roll Your Own Linked List/Tree in R?

Tags: r, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, reference

I'm trying to wrap my head around the basic concepts of the R programming language and am finding it difficult since R is geared towards statistics instead of general-purpose programming.  I can't find anything similar to pointers/references.  How would you implement a linked list, search tree, etc. within the R language?

Note:  I understand that if you're actually rolling your own self-referential data structures in R, there's probably a better way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  However, I believe an answer will help me understand the overall structure and concepts of the language better.

Edit:  With regard to Matt Shotwell's comment, the point of this question is that I'm looking to write linked lists and trees **cleanly, within** R, not as an extension written in C or some other language.  Doing it as an extension or by mucking with arcane details of the interpreter defeats the purpose.

Comment: Here are a couple of leads: 1) ?parilist 2) search 'weak reference' and 'external pointer' in the 'R Internals' manual and 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A linked list in R can be represented as a vector, typically a `list`. You don't need to write special code to reference the next and previous items, because R does it for you via indexing.

To add a new item to the list, just keep track of its length and assign to the next in line.

```
lst <- list() # creates an empty (length zero) list
lst[[1]] <- 1 # automagically extends the lst
lst[[2]] <- 2 # ditto
```

This can be inefficient for long lists because of the way R handles memory. If possible, create the list in advance, and assign their contents as they become available.

```
lst <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)    # a list of 5 items

lst <- vector("list", 10000)  # 10000 NULLs
lst[[1]] <- 1
lst[[10000]] <- 10000  # lst now contains 1, NULL, ..., NULL, 10000
```

Deleting an item from the list can be accomplished with negative indexes.

```
lst <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
lst <- lst[-2]  # now contains 1, 3, 4, 5
```

A tree is just a list containing other lists.

```
tree <- list(list(1, 2), list(3, list(4, 5)))

# left child: list(1, 2)
tree[[1]]

# right child
tree[[2]]

# right child of right child:list(4, 5)
tree[[2]][[2]]
```

By default there is no built-in enforcing of the structure, eg only two children per node for a binary tree. More structured approaches are available via S4 classes, but this will do the job in a pinch.

Comment: At the internal level, a `list` is just a type of vector.  A `pairlist` is a true linked list.

Comment: @Joshua: true, but for most things you'd want a linked list for, a regular `list` will work just fine and be less obscure especially for someone new to R.

Comment: @HongOoi: I completely agree. I was just pointing out that a list-vector is not technically a linked-list. You show that you can use it as one, but that's not what's going on internally.

Comment: @Joshua: fair enough, I'll edit the answer to clarify my intention.