# Is there a collections library in R?

Tags: r

Is there a collections library in R that has the rough equivalent of what is in Java's  is in java.util.Collections:

1. Various Distionaries
2. Various Trees
3. Various Bags
4. etc.

Comment: Maybe the `hash` package is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such package that implements all the features of collections. **Dataframes** are the easiest and fun way to manipulate data. However, we can use lists for most of the functionality of linked-lists, stack and queues. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219476/roll-your-own-linked-list-tree-in-r) is how it is done.

Edit: For optimal results, implementation of linkedlists using lists is **not recommended** because of the way in which R allocates memory.

Hope it helped!