# how to create doubly linked list in R programming language?

Tags: r, doubly-linked-list

how to doubly linked list in R studio?

```
dlinkListNode <- function(val, prevnode=NULL, node=NULL) { 
  llist <- new.env(parent=create_emptyenv())
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In this case, we need to see your sample input data and your expected output.  Your current function will do nothing because it creates a local variable (`llist`) and returns `NULL`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219476/roll-your-own-linked-list-tree-in-r) answer your question?

Comment: @Limey related but not the same